# Put thumbnail highlighter to the rightmost image

Tags: magento-2.1

On Product page, the image highlighter is always on the first image on the left by default.

I want to shift it to rightmost image by default.

[image]

Comment: you need to change in magento core file for this, or you can do this via custom extension rewrite.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I can override core files once I figure out how to do that.

Comment: Have you used any custom theme ?

Comment: yes, i've made my own custom theme. Why does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your question really interesting so took a deep dive in this problem.
As you mentioned earlier you are looking for exactly what code to change for this, not the full process of creating theme and overriding it. 
From my research I have found that

> /var/www/html//lib/web/fotorama.js

file is responsible for highlighting whichever image you want.

You can change the value of variable **startindex** (**default set to 0**) to any larger values so that it will always start with lastmost item in the thumbnail slider.

> It is not good to modify codes in core as it will get overwritten when
>   upgrading so it's better to extend or override fotorama.js in your theme or extension as you like. You can follow this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/extending-magento-2-default-js-components/) to get idea of overriding the core js.

```
Do not forget to clear cache, deploy static-content.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anime. you are right. But in my case the image with index 0 is taking the rightmost spot. Any idea from where does gallery calls the images?

Comment: I'll check that.

Comment: Have you tried with a negative or a large value. Let me know the results.

Comment: negative value: it remains on first image; very large: moves to last image

Comment: Then you have the solution. Cheers.